# jhipster index.html not allowing changes

Tags: jhipster, webpack-4

I created a jhipster ui only angular 6 app.
I now want to add a script to index.html:

```
<head>
...

<script src='widgets/widgets.js'></script>

</head>
```

When I run the index.html is copied to the build/www directory fine, but in the app my script tag or any other changes are not there.
Seems that webpack does not use my new version.
How do I get webpack to use the changed template?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use webpack in order to achieve the script tag injection.

Add your script to the entry points of webpack in the `entry` property located in webpack.dev.js (or prod) file, then add the related key inside the `chunks` array of the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` (it is located in webpack.common file).

This should inject the script tag inside your index.html